# How to check if the field contains hyphen character in java

Tags: java

My Object returns me `-` from 
    Log.d("FormattedDate", Object.getDOB());

```
if (!Object.getDOB().matches("[^-]*")) {
    txtDOB.setText(Object.getDOB());
   } else {
    txtDOB.setText("-");
}
```

I am checking if my Object.getDOB() matches with `-`, then show emptry strings, but this regExp is not working.

Comment: Simply use String.contains method, but are you sure this '-' is not added by the Logger?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[java.lang.String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) has a [String#contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method that does this for you:

> Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified
>   sequence of char values.

```
if (Object.getDOB().contains("-")) {
    //code
}
```

Comment: Strangely, it does not work in Java 8. I am spending hours in this stupid problem. I cannot split 'Flesch–Kincaid' by '-'

Comment: It doesnt work for me selectedProductName=  selectedProductName.replaceAll("-", "");

Comment: @AkashChavan `String.replaceAll` takes regex as the first parameter and hyphen (`"-"`) is a special character in regex, so you must escape it. Try `selectedProductName= selectedProductName.replaceAll("\\-", "");`

Comment: Any way to see if a String contains a character multiple times?

Comment: @jDub9 sure you can: `String[] parts = text.split(CHARACTER);`
`int occurances = parts.length - 1;`

Answer (score 3):

You could also use

```
if (Object.getDOB().indexOf("-") != -1) {
    //code
}
```

if it returns `-1` then the string does not contain the char (in your case `"-"`). Otherwise it returns the index of the char.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `contains()` in java to search which is available in `String` class

> Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified
>   sequence of char values.

```
getDOB().contains("-")
```

[**SEE HERE**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)